# What's the meaning of '#x.x' in assemble copiled by icc?

Tags: c, intel, icc

I compile come simple code with intel icc compiler, and I notice that there are some numbers at the end of each line. I wanna know the meaning.

Just like `#3.12` in the following code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 3, b;
    scanf("%d", &b);
    a = a + b;
    printf("Hello, world! I am %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

```
...
main:
..B1.1:                         # Preds ..B1.0
                                # Execution count [1.00e+00]
..L1:
                                                          #3.12
        pushl     %ebp                                          #3.12
        movl      %esp, %ebp                                    #3.12
        andl      $-128, %esp                                   #3.12
...
```

Comment: Line and column number of the corresponding C code? The ICC manual mentions something called _"#line directives, which the compiler uses to determine the source file and line number"_. But it doesn't specify the format of those directives as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Michael You are both right and wrong. The numbers are the line and column of the corresponding code, but they are not directly related to the [`#line` directive](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzarg/lc.htm) which is used to manually set the value of the internal macros `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` during compilation (indirectly they are related in the way that setting the line number with the `#line` directive will affect the line number shown in the assembly output).

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed the line and column of the corresponding source code. #3.12 is the opening `{`  of the main function which makes sense since the shown statements are consistent with the start of a function.

If you insert an extra space before the `{` you will see that the output changes to `#3.13`; likewise the `3` changes to `4` if you insert an empty line before the `main()`function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure for preparing the start of a function, also called the function header. Here we hide the return address on the stack and allocate empty space on the stack for the function to work. Pay attention at the end is the reverse process. Here is an example of the same from another compiler:

```
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 8
        ...
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
```

Comment: The OP is asking how ICC chooses the numbers for its comments, not what the instructions on those lines actually do.

Comment: sorry? i don't understand him